# Rails Activerecord cannot get object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I want to test whether csv import method persist product object correctly. It seems product object persisted correctly, but cannot assert product object's field. How can I assert product object's field?

Console Output

```
expected: "productE"
     got: "Spree::Product" (using ==)
./spec/models/spree/csv_import_spec.rb:31:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

csv_import_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe Spree::CsvImport do
  context "" do
    let!(:product_target) { create(:product_target)}
    let!(:product_category) { create(:product_category)}
    let!(:brand) { create(:brand, name: 'Araki Yuu', product_category: product_category)}
    let!(:tax_category) { create(:tax_category, name: 'Default')}
    let!(:shipping_category) { create(:shipping_category, name: 'Everywhere')}
    let!(:zone1) { create(:zone, name: 'Japan')}
    let!(:zone2) { create(:zone, name: 'US')}
    let!(:taxon) { create(:taxon, name: 'SHIRTS')}
    let!(:option_type) { create(:option_type, name: 'SHIRTS')}
    let!(:option_value) { create(:option_value, name: 'M')}
    let!(:measurement_type) { create(:measurement_type)}
    let!(:stock_location) { create(:stock_location, name: 'KIEI Tokyo')}
    it "" do
      # Spree::CsvImport.import('csv_import_spec_1.csv')
      Spree::CsvImport.import(
          Class.new(Class.new do
            def self.path
              'spec/models/spree/csv_import_spec_1.csv'
            end
          end
          )
      )
    end

    it "should ..." do
      product = Spree::Product.where(:product_sku => 'productE')
      product.name.should == 'productE'

          # find_by_product_sku('productE').should be_true
      # Product.find_by_product_sku('productE').should be_true
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: try: `product = Spree::Product.where(:product_sku => 'productE').first` instead? Otherwise `product` is actually a relation/collection, not a single actual product.

Comment: `where` will never return you a single product, always a relation.